# C# download image from src without extension

Tags: c#, image, url, download

I would like to download an image from this url http://squirlytraffic.com/surficon.php?ts=1491591235

I tried this code but I don't see the image when I open it.

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
  {
    client.DownloadFile("http://squirlytraffic.com/surficon.php?ts=1491591235", @"D:\image.jpg");         
  }
```

Comment: The url redirect to login, you need to authenticate before you download image

Comment: I'm logged in in the webbrowser.

Comment: No you have to do it from web client

Answer (score 0):

You need to set your credentials using the the WebClient Credentials property. You can do this by assigning it an instance of [NetworkCredential](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkcredential(v=vs.110).aspx).  See below:

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient()){
  client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user-name", "password");
  client.DownloadFile("url", @"file-location");
}
```

**EDIT**

If you don't want to hard code a username and password, you can set the UseDefaultCredentials property of the WebClient to true. This will use the credentials of the currently logged in user. From the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.credentials.aspx).

> The Credentials property contains the authentication credentials used to access a resource on a host. In most client-side scenarios, you should use the DefaultCredentials, which are the credentials of the currently logged on user. To do this, set the UseDefaultCredentials property to true instead of setting this property.

Which would mean you could amend the above code to:

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient()){
  client.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
  client.DownloadFile("url", @"file-location");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way, those parameters are passed when login

```
            StringBuilder postData = new StringBuilder();
            postData.Append("login=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode("username") + "&");
            postData.Append("password=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode("password") + "&");
            postData.Append("Submit=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode("Login"));
            ASCIIEncoding ascii = new ASCIIEncoding();
            byte[] postBytes = ascii.GetBytes(postData.ToString());
            CookieContainer cc = new CookieContainer();
            HttpWebRequest webReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://squirlytraffic.com/members.php");
            webReq.Method = "POST";
            webReq.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            webReq.ContentLength = postBytes.Length;
            webReq.UserAgent = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727)";
            webReq.CookieContainer = cc;
            Stream postStream = webReq.GetRequestStream();
            postStream.Write(postBytes, 0, postBytes.Length);
            postStream.Flush();
            postStream.Close();
            HttpWebResponse res = (HttpWebResponse)webReq.GetResponse();
            HttpWebRequest ImgReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://squirlytraffic.com/surficon.php?ts=1491591235");
            ImgReq.Method = "GET";
            ImgReq.UserAgent = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727)";
            ImgReq.CookieContainer = cc;
            HttpWebResponse ImgRes = (HttpWebResponse)ImgReq.GetResponse();
            Stream Img = ImgRes.GetResponseStream();
```

Comment: Not work. How can I check if I logged in with webrequest?

Comment: And if this code download the image where can I find the image in my drive?

Comment: After login the response HTML will show a after login page, the above code just retrieve stream you need to write that stream to a file